# Oracle throwing ORA-16198 on database switch over

Tags: database, oracle

We are trying to do a manual failover of our oracle database servers through enterprise manager and it keeps throwing an ORA-16198 timeout incurred on internal channel during remote archival. How do I go about troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: "data ass servers" sounds...weird.

Comment: Got to love the spell checker on the iPhone

Answer (score 1):

is this a production issue, or are you just working in a test environment? If its production... talk to oracle support.